# Crop PDFContext in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, pdf, crop

I'd like to create an infinite PDF Context in Objective-C in an Mac OS x app and crop it afterwards before saving, once I know the size of the production. It is easy to create an infinite PDFContext with CGPDFContextCreateWithURL, but it is impossible to display afterwards with Preview.

Answer (score 0):

In Similar situations I solved similar problems with another approach.

In a first step I computed some (custom) meta file in which I just noticed which graphical elements along with its properties and coordinates (endless world coordinates, not related to any output device or format) the graphic would have. 
By doing so I took hold of the maximum x and y coodrinates ever used.

I did not do that on iOS but if I would, then I would certainly use some core data or just a plain sqlite table for that.

Next step would be to break down the meta coordinates into resonable tile of which each correlates to something like a pdf page in your case. These tiles would consider the x/y ratio of the target paper format, landscape or portrait ect. You may want the user to choose and provide a preview page.

Then I'd finally render the pdfs page by page. When you ignore all graphical objects that are completely out of bounds of the current page, then the rendering should be quite fast. Some smart sorting of the meta items by the x and then the y of the top left coordinate of each object, you can improve the performance even more.

I guess you will be surprised how fast this can work, when you do it right.